# Multiple forms with field name arrays fail vaildation

Tags: validation, laravel-4

I have multiple forms in a tabbed layout and post to the same resource controller. These fields have the same field names with a few as arrays. Use case is password storage where depending on the type of password depends on the fields needed.

Input field

```
<?= Form::text('name', Input::old('name'), array('class' => ($errors->has('name')) ? 'invalid' : '', 'placeholder' => 'Application Name')) ?>
<?= Form::text("data['username']", Input::old('data["username"]'), array('class' => ($errors->has('data.username')) ? 'invalid' : '', 'placeholder' => 'Username')) ?>
<?= Form::text("data['password']", Input::old('data["password"]'), array('class' => ($errors->has('data.password')) ? 'invalid' : '', 'placeholder' => 'Password')) ?>
```

Validation rules

```
protected $rules = array(
    'name'          => 'required',
    'data.username' => 'required',
    'data.password' => 'required'
);
```

I have more data fields but this illustrates the use case.

I get errors properly with posting with empty fields and the old input is populated but I also get errors for filled fields. My post data shows populated fields.

Answer (score 0):

Tested with just one form (could have done that the first time) and still had the error. My issue here was with the how the `data['username']` was used.

Should be `data[username]` without the quotes. While post data and everything works with the quotes, the validator was not liking it.